# image not shown in background in css

Tags: css, reactjs, background-image

when I try to pass a image template to style in react element, the image doesn't show up in the background.

```
<div className="avatar">
  <span style={{background:`url('/images/covers/${this.state.artists.cover}.jpg') no-repeat`}}></span>
</div>
```

when I try to inspect the element. it shows

```
<span></span>
```

the style is not set. what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Probably, your expression `'/images/covers/${this.state.artists.cover}.jpg'` is not parsed by engine because you used simple string without escaping and string literal can't transform the expression `${this.state.artists.cover}` into the value.

So, you need to do something like this:

```
<div className="avatar">
  <span style={{background:`url(\'/images/covers/${this.state.artists.cover}.jpg\') no-repeat`}}></span>
</div>
```

Hope it will helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
style={{"background: url("  + ( this.state.artists.cover ) + ")" }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I don't see your css, and I think I see the problem.
The fact is the `<span>` tag is inline element - it can't have image on backround while it is empty.

You should add some block styles to it (or place some content into it)

```
span {
    display: block; // or inline-block
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

and then don't play hard with ticks - in this case you can use only a single ones

```
<span style={{background: 'url(https://lilpickmeupdotcom.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/happy-smile-guy.jpg)'}}></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using webpack you should set a loader such [url-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/url-loader) to use jpg files in JSX. Then you should import the jpg photo before using it like this:

```
<div className="avatar">
    <span style={{ background: `url(${require(`./images/covers/${this.state.artists.cover}.jpg`)}) no-repeat` }} />
</div>
```

Or like this:

```
<div className="avatar">
    <span style={{ background: `url(${require(`url-loader!./images/covers/${this.state.artists.cover}.jpg`)}) no-repeat` }} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in Kotsur's answer, your expression contains some characters like `'` so it is not parsed. But you should encode `this.state.artists.cover` rather than encoding quotes outside.

Try something like:

```
<div className="avatar">
  <span style={{background:`url('/images/covers/${encodeURIComponent(this.state.artists.cover).replace("'", "\\'")}.jpg') no-repeat`}}></span>
</div>
```